# REST Web-services eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rest, servlets

I am new to REST Web services and was following a tutorial in Youtube. Although i followed the exact steps, I am unable to successfully run it. 
Here is what i did 
web.xml file

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/resteasy</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the service class that i created.

```
@Path("service")
public class Service {

private static Map<Integer , DoctorInformation> doctorInformations = new HashMap<Integer , DoctorInformation>();

static{
    Location location = new Location();

    location.setCity("Roorkee");
    location.setState("Uttarakhand");

    DoctorInformation doctorInformation = new DoctorInformation();
    doctorInformation.setID(1);
    doctorInformation.setFirstName("Sanchit");
    doctorInformation.setLastName("Jain");
    doctorInformation.setAddressLine1("ABSGDHD");
    doctorInformation.setAddressLIne2("NBAJS");
    doctorInformation.setPincode(247667);
    doctorInformation.setEmail("@gmail.com");
    doctorInformation.setSpecialization("ENT");
    doctorInformation.setLocation(location);

    doctorInformations.put(1 , doctorInformation);
}

//Method that will return single person object in XML

@GET        
@Path ("/getPersonByIdXML/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public DoctorInformation getPersonByIdXML(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return doctorInformations.get(id); 
}
```

I am using Maven to build the project , and finally when the Web project is deployed in localhost i am using the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/Project_Name/service/getPersonByIdXML/1
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong. I think the <**url-patter**> in my web.xml is not proper, but when i changed it even the index.html page that loads on `http://localhost:8080/Project_Name/` stopped working. In many places i have seen that <**init-param**> is defined along with ...somthing like this...

```
init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.package.whatever</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but in my example i am using `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher` as my servlet class. How will it make the difference?

The **exception** displayed on console is :

```
SEVERE: failed to execute
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/TestWS/resteasy/service/getPersonByIdXML/1
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Does hitting : http://localhost:8080/Project_Name/resteasy/service/getPersonByIdXML/1
give you any results ?

Comment: I am afraid not...i had already tried this combination...

Comment: Okay. What exception do you see ? I'm assuming you see an error/exception/message when you run the url.

Comment: added the exception to the question

Comment: Alright. So can you add a couple of sysouts/loggers to see if your code is at least being invoked ? I do not see any issue right now, might need to create a project and see from there. In the mean while you can go through this : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/resteasy/resteasy-hello-world-example/ and see if you have any significant differences.

Comment: In my Service class, I put a `system.out.println` in static block but nothing is displaying in console. What could be the possible cause for it. My web.xml is placed at TestWS->src->main->webapp->WEB-INF->web.xml

Comment: If you move all the code to the function getPersonByIdByXML,  then ?

Comment: **resteasy-servlet-initializer** depedency had to be added to pom.xml. But now i have another problem. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491679/org-jboss-resteasy-plugins-server-servlet-httpservletdispatcher-cannot-be-cast-t) it is. How to resolve this now?